# Why is Bigelow BA330 expandable instead of fitting fairings?

Tags: space-station, bigelow, expandable

[Bigelow Aerospace](http://www.bigelowaerospace.com/) develops expandable (inflatable/foldable) space stations. Their flagship is their cylindrical [BA330](http://www.bigelowaerospace.com/ba330.php) which has the dimensions 13.7 by 6.7 meter when expanded. Current ISS modules seem to have a diameter of less than 5 meter. But this is not far from the dimensions of fairings of [Atlas V](http://www.ulalaunch.com/products_atlasv.aspx), [Delta IV Heavy](http://www.boeing.com/boeing/defense-space/space/delta/delta4/delta4.page), [Proton](http://www.khrunichev.ru/main.php?id=42&lang=en) and [Ariane 5](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Launchers/Launch_vehicles/Ariane_5_ECA2). They have 5.0-5.4 meter fairing diameter. The mass of the BA330 (20-23 tons) is on the limit of what those rockets can launch to LEO. [SLS](http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2012/11/nasa-payload-fairings-options-multi-mission-sls-capability/) might get fairings with up to 10 meter diameter.

So why go through the extra trouble of making their space station expandable? Is the extra 1.3-1.7 meter diameter so important? Wouldn't a static structure, maybe made by the same materials, be much simpler and cheaper to develop and manufacture, lighter and less risky to deploy in space?

If the BA330 is primarily a technology demonstration, what would be the use of space station modules which have larger diameter than the payload fairings of today's and near-future launchers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That 5.0 meters is the outer diameter of the payload fairing. Payloads obviously cannot be that large. In fact, they are constrained to be a bit smaller. The figures below depicts the Delta IV Heavy and Atlas V static volume (volume that a payload can occupy).

http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~lafever/SNAP/OldFiles/DELTA%20PAYLOAD%20OVERVIEW_files/d4hfairings.gif
<sup>Image source: http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~lafever/SNAP/OldFiles/DELTA%20PAYLOAD%20OVERVIEW.htm</sup>

[image]
<sup>Image source: http://www.ulalaunch.com/products_atlasv.aspx</sup>

Note that the Delta IV Heavy and Atlas V both constrain payloads to 4.57 meters in diameter. One would think that the Ariane 5 with its 5.4 meter fairing would accommodate a wider payload. This is not the case. The Ariane 5 accommodates the same size payload as does a Delta IV Heavy or Atlas V. A Proton M is in the same class.

That 4.57 meters includes space for the un-deployed solar arrays and for vibrations. One would be hard pressed to launch a standalone rigid structure much bigger than the 4.2 meter diameter [ISS Destiny module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny_(ISS_module)) on an existing launch vehicle. Yes, we can wait (and wait and wait) for the Senate Launch System to come on line, but it's going to be a long wait.

That increase from 4.2 meters to 6.7 meters in diameter alone is quite significant. That's a 60% increase in diameter, or a 154% increase in cross section area. The volume increases even more with inflatables thanks to length. The BA330 will have over three times the pressurized volume of the Destiny module.

**References:**

Section 6, "Payload Fairings," of the [Delta IV Users Guide](http://www.ulalaunch.com/uploads/docs/Launch_Vehicles/Delta_IV_Users_Guide_June_2013.pdf) describes the constraints on payload size on a Delta IV.

Section 6, "Payload Fairings," of the [Atlas V Launch Services User's Guide](http://www.ulalaunch.com/uploads/docs/AtlasVUsersGuide2010.pdf) describes the constraints on payload size on an Atlas V.

Annex 5, "Usable volume under fairing and SYLDA 5," of the [Ariane 5 User's Manual](http://www.arianespace.com/launch-services-ariane5/Ariane5_users_manual_Issue5_July2011.pdf) describes the constraints on payload size on an Ariane 5.

Answer (score 2):

Usable volume rises quickly with radius (r<sup>2</sup>) so a cylinder with a diameter of 6.7 m has almost twice the usable volume of a cylinder of 5 m diameter.